# Using MS mail rest API, how can I track a message among the domain users?

Tags: rest, email, ms-office, office365, office365-restapi

For each mail message fetched using MS mail REST API I can get the **ConversationId** which is used to identify the mail thread for the message in user's folders.

The problem with **ConversationId** is that it is unique for each user, not for all domain users.

If I want to track the message for all domain users that receives the message. How could I accomplish that using the MS APIs?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the API since the o365 Api is for items identified by the server components such as: message id, appointment id, ...etc but not for client generated ids.